# Acer Aspire One D255 -- can I use a battery from a D250?

Tags: netbook, battery

Does anyone know if a 6 cell battery from an Acer One D250 will fit in my D255?

Answer (score 1):

My parts list has them as separate items with different stock codes so I would say no. Add the part code of the battery that you have to your question and I will check it further just in case.

Edit just checked - the contacts are in completely different positions so that's a definite 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

As an owner of a D255, the answer is NO, which sucks because the D255 battery (6 cell and up) is much more expensive than the D250 batteries. As of now, anyway. :(

Answer (score -1):

It depends on a number of factors, such as power output as well as physical chassis design.

I highly recommend that you ask Acer about this directly to get the best answer.

Comment: I don't understand why this got voted as "not useful."  It is a correct answer that is actually helpful because it will help the questioner find the right answer.

Comment: Possibly because it doesn't really *provide* an answer. After all, every question on this site could be 'answered' with "You may find an answer if you try Google" !!

Comment: I agree that "If you try Google" is not a useful answer, but in this case the questioner is asking a very model-specific question where the manufacturer is undoubtedly the best source of the needed proprietary information (and will very likely provide the correct information for free).  Providing information on how to find the answer is sometimes important too, as I believe is the case here (if you check the answers I provide to other questions you'll see that I almost always provide detailed solutions or suggestions for helpful projects/products that can lead to a solution).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the answer is a resounding "no". They are made completely differently and don't fit together. It's unfortunate because the D250 battery is so much cheaper!